# Offsetting raster layers in GeoServer SLD

Tags: geoserver, sld

Is it possible to scale or offset raster layers in GeoServer SLD, for example to convert Kelvin to Celsius on the fly?

Given a basic raster style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>sample_raster</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Sample Raster</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <RasterSymbolizer>
            <ColorMap>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#000000" quantity="0"  label="values"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#FFFFFF" quantity="20"  label="values"/>
            </ColorMap>
          </RasterSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

presumably something like

```
<ogc:Add>
    <ogc:Function name="parameter">
        <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Function>
    <ogc:Literal>-273.15</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:Add>
```

needs to be incorporated somewhere, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to include this correctly.

Comment: I have same issue. If data is stored in degrees Kelvin and my output will be in Celsius... How do I configure/setup GeoServer to serve the same data without any modification? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you can't.

Longer answer, it would not be too hard to code a rendering transformation to do that as part of styling. Probably a day of work not more. All the machinery is in  place, there is already a rescale coverage operation in GeoTools that you can hook as a raster rendering transformation.

Simone.

Answer (score 3):

### Update 6/2018:

In case someone finds this later.
This problem can currently be easily solved using Jiffle scripting language as a  rendering transformation in **development build** of Geoserver with WPS processing plugin installed.

Sample code:

```
<Transformation>
  <ogc:Function name="ras:Jiffle">
    <ogc:Function name="parameter">
      <ogc:Literal>coverage</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Function>
    <ogc:Function name="parameter">
      <ogc:Literal>script</ogc:Literal>
      <ogc:Literal>
        temp = src[0];
        subt = 273.15;
        dest = temp - subt;
      </ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Function>
  </ogc:Function>
</Transformation>
```

Comment: Jiffle seems to be in GeoServer 2.14 WPS per http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html#running-map-algebra-on-the-fly-using-jiffle   Do you still need a development build or does this work for Stable?

Comment: Yes, this is corrent. 2.14.0 release already contains Jiffle. http://blog.geoserver.org/2018/09/24/geoserver-2-14-0-released/